# Tracking code not installed (Google Analytics)

Tags: php, google-analytics

i'm trying to install google analytics tracking to my site but keep getting this message "Status: Tracking not installed", although i implemented it exactly as google wants it.

here's my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <link href='/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body>
Test
</body></html>
```

of course i put the correct UA-Code instead of the XXXX .. when checking the site's sourcecode, it's showing the exact snippet as given in google analytics ..
i've refreshed and waited for almost an hour now, no success :(
any ideas what's wrong?
thanks

Comment: Does the domain of your website match what you see on the Google Analytics page?

Comment: By default it doesn't show the current day, did you try looking at the real time stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the real time stats in GA, it wont show your current day for at least a few hours, sometimes the live stats even take a few hours to kick in.

Also inside GA you can check to see if they can see thew code, if they say they can then your ok

Give it some more time

Sources: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en

Comment: yes - it takes some time, today it works :) strange thing .. as google tells that it checks each 2-5 minutes.